# Error with cooldown script on Discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am getting an error when I run my bot that has a cooldown script for a command where you can claim money in a guild, except you can only claim it once every 3 minutes.
This is what my code looks like:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const talkedRecently = new Set();
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login('Redacted', () => {
console.log('dahelper connected via nodejs servers');
});
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '!hello') {
    message.channel.send('Hello to you too!');
  }
});

    if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {
            message.channel.send("You can only use this command once every 3 minutes, use it wisely! - " + msg.author);
    } else {
            client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '!claim') {
    message.channel.send('You have claimed 250 guild moneys.');
  }
  });

        // Adds the user to the set so that they can't talk for a minute
        talkedRecently.add(msg.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          // Removes the user from the set after a minute
          talkedRecently.delete(msg.author.id);
        }, 180000);
    }
```

I get an error that's saying "if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) msg is not defined". And I know why. Because I never declared "msg" anywhere in the code, it doesn't know what I'm looking for, and in this case, I should change everything that says "msg" to "message" I tried this, and I got the same error, in the same place, except it said, "message is not defined."

Answer (score 0):

Your code is outside of the handler for the message event:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '!hello') {
    message.channel.send('Hello to you too!');
  }
} /* Function ends here */);
// The rest of your code is outside of it
    if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) { // ...
```

You should put it inside the function after making sure to use the right variable name.

Comment: I tried wrapping the code in the function (i.e putting the }); at the end) and I got a "Missing ); after argument list" error because the code is expecting ); after the function code. What do I do?